# square root and struct in opencl

Tags: opencl

I want to use two things in my OpenCL kernel, which I don't know how to implement/use. The easiest to answer I guess is how to use a square root. The only useful thing I found is [this](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf), but I don't get much wiser from it. Can I just type hypot(A, B), and then it calculates the square root from A² + B²? And what if I want to use doubles with it? It says I have to use an extension, but how do I use that?

Second I want to ask is how to use a typedef struct in OpenCL, better, how to pass it?
To make it "visual":

I have this struct, a quite simple one:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
}Coord;
```

I want to pass an array of these to my kernel. Each thread has to get his own x and y with the global id it gets.

So how do I make sure that the thread is able to do that? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try reading the [full spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf) if the reference card doesn't have enough info.

Answer (score 1):

To enable usage of double-precision, as you have already pointed out, you must specify an extension to use in the beginning of your OpenCL code (i.e. where your `__kernel` is):

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

After doing this, you should be able to use `double2` data type, which is the same as your `Coord` structure, but is understandable by compiler, so could be better optimized. And `hypot` will be able to use doubles too.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL includes a square root builtín function "sqrt" (see section 6.11.2 of the OpenCL specification [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf), which is an overloaded function taking and returning float, and the vector of float types (float2,3,4,8.16), and if the `cl_chr_fp64` extension is enabled via pragma, it accepts the double types and vector of double types too.

The typedef can be used both inside OpenCL code, and in host code i.e. in OpenCL, you can have an array of structs, as you would in C. You would need to use the array of structs as an input to the kernel in the host code, and declare a kernel argument of type `global Coord* array` in your kernel (assuming your array will reside in OpenCL global memory.

To use the global_id as an index into arrays, you can use the value returned by `get_global_id`

```
size_t i = get_global_id(0);
array[i].x = ...
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I can just pass an array of Coord to a kernel, without doing any extra stuff? Why isn't it working then, giving very weird results?

I've made a very simple code to just test the typedef struct thing, and it isn't geving the results as expected. Can someone tell me why? I feel kinda dumb now to be honest...:P

main: http://pastebin.com/hAtjMsDz

kernel: http://pastebin.com/AZLyz0Hw